# How to remove the "+" and "-" after a diff comparison

Tags: cygwin, diff, mobaxterm

I compare 2 files using Cygwin (MobaXterm) diff.
Output files have -- a  and ++ b lines at the first line. I want to delete only these lines. How could I do it?
Here's my script:

```
#! /bin/bash

sort -bf $1 | uniq > a
sort -bf $2 | uniq > b
/drives/c/Software/MobaXterm_Portable_v22.0/slash/bin/diff -iw a b > c
rm a b
grep ^'+' c | awk '{sub("+","");{print}}' | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' > $1_only.txt
grep ^'-' c | awk '{sub("-","");{print}}' | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' > $2_only.txt
rm c
```

--
Here's the output from one file:

```
++ b
2
4
6
```

Here's the output from another file:

```
-- a
3
5
```

Thanks

Comment: You missing a perl in the pipe chain...

Comment: Add to the chain another command to remove the first line - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339483/how-can-i-remove-the-first-line-of-a-text-file-using-bash-sed-script).

Comment: All set. Adding sed command to delete the first line solved my issue. 
Thank you.